# Getting multi-part identifier "column name" could not be bound error in SQL Server of newer version

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this code for my stored procedure:

```
create or alter procedure udpReservationFilter
    @FName nvarchar(160),
    @LName nvarchar(160),
    @Category nvarchar(160),
    @Number int,
    @TotalCount int OUT,
    @ColumnName nvarchar(100) = 'M.Id',
    @SortDesc bit = 0,
    @Page int = 1,
    @PageSize int = 2
as
begin
    declare @sqlWhere nvarchar(max) = ''
    declare @whereParams nvarchar(1000) = N' @FName nvarchar(160),
                                             @LName nvarchar(160),
                                             @Category nvarchar(160),
                                             @Number int, @OffsetRows int, @PageSize int'

    declare @countParams nvarchar(1000) = N' @FName nvarchar(160),
                                             @LName nvarchar(160),
                                             @Category nvarchar(160),
                                             @Number int,
                                             @TotalCount int OUT'

    if len(trim(@FName)) > 0
        set @sqlWhere += ' AND c.FName like ''%'' + @FName + ''%''  '

    if len(trim(@LName)) > 0
        set @sqlWhere += ' AND c.LName like @LName '

    if len(trim(@Category))> 0
        set @sqlWhere += ' AND r.Category like  @Category  '

    if (@Number > 0)
        set @sqlWhere += ' AND r.Number = @Number '

    ---------------- counting total results -------------------
    declare @sqlCount nvarchar(1000) = N' select @TotalCount = count(*) from Reservations M ' 

    if len(@sqlWhere) > 0
        set @sqlCount = @sqlCount + ' where ' + (SUBSTRING(@sqlWhere, 5 , 60)) 
        
    exec sp_executesql  @sqlCount, 
                        @countParams,
                        @FName = @FName,
                        @LName = @LName,
                        @Category = @Category,
                        @Number = @Number,
                        @TotalCount = @TotalCount OUT

    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N' select M.*, c.*, r.Category, r.Number, r.Price, r.Status
                            from Reservations M, Client c, Rooms r
                            where M.ClientId=c.ID and M.RoomId=r.Id' 
                + @sqlWhere
                + ' order by ' + @ColumnName
                + ' offset @OffsetRows rows fetch next @PageSize rows only'
                --M.*, c.*, r.Number, r.category, r.Price, r.status

    declare @Offset int = (@Page-1)*@PageSize

    if @Offset < 0
      set @Offset = 0

    exec sp_executesql @sql, 
                @whereParams, 
                @FName = @FName,
                @LName  =@LName,
                @Category = @Category,
                @Number = @Number,
                @OffsetRows = @Offset,
                @PageSize = @PageSize
end
```

I'm getting this error:

> The multi-part identifier "column_name" could not be bound.

when executing the query.

```
declare @cnt int

exec udpReservationFilter 
    @FName = null,
    @LName = null,
    @Category = null,
    @Number = null,
    @TotalCount = @cnt OUT,
    @PageSize = 3
```

When I provide parameters it is above error and gives the matched result this error stops my asp.net core app and if there is no parameters provided its compiling without error

Here is more detailed error :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> The multi-part identifier "c.FName" could not be bound.
>
> (1 row affected)

Comment: It's **2022**, the ANSI-92 explicit Join Syntax has been around for **30 years**, why are you yet to adopt it?

Comment: I would imagine it is the statement stored in `@sqlCount` that is giving the error.  What does `SUBSTRING(@sqlwhere, 5, 60)` return?  What is the value `@sqlCount` if you PRINT it?

Comment: The problem is the dynamic SQL query, not the SQL Server version. The final SQL statement is invalid. Check the actual contents of `@sql`. If possible though, *don't* generate queries like this on the server. You gain little (if anything), they're very hard to debug and you really don't know what gets executed. The equivalent LINQ query would be a lot simpler

Comment: @squillman sqlCount returns total number of rows on the table for paging. about substring its just concats the string

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos there is task to use stored procedure to filter.
it was working on other project this one is a bit refactored in a way that table names, properties, datatypes are changed

Comment: Have a look at [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: @AkbarjonAbdukarimov I understand what `@sqlCount` _should_ do.  My question is what is it _really_ doing?

Comment: @AkbarjonAbdukarimov did you check the final `@sql` string? Did you try to execute it? What's at line 5? It's impossible to help without knowing what the query is. The error complains that `c` in line 5, which seems to be an alias for `Client`, doesn't have a `FName` field. The error is correct which means that either `c` isn't Client, or `Client` really doesn't have that column.